# AQtime not working properly on windows vista / 7 with multi-core processor

Tags: performance, windows-7, windows-vista, profiler, aqtime

I'm tryin to run AQtime (v5.45), as preformance profiler under windows vista or 7 on my multi-core laptop but it seems that the program is not working correctly, he does not show any routine and seems to throw an exception when trying to call InstallCustomModule in clr.dll,
i tried to install a demo version of AQtime 7 which is working perfectly with both vista and seven, i'm trying to get an answer on how to get the v5.45 to work from the support of AQtime Team, but i still have no answer ...

I was wondering if someone had the same problem and if someone fixed it in some way ? or if the only way is to get a new v7 license ?

thanks in advance ;)

here are more infos about the exception on the vista machine :

```
Event   Thread ID   Time
First chance exception 0x04242420 Unknown exception occurred at 0x75E2FBAE  1952    19:11:01:529
0x75E2FBAE RaiseException + 0x58 in kernel32.dll    1952    
0x5BC60D08 InstallCustomModule + 0x35405 in clr.dll 1952    
0x5B9672AF InitializeFusion + 0x6A30 in clr.dll 1952    
0x5B966CB7 InitializeFusion + 0x6438 in clr.dll 1952    
0x5B966ADD InitializeFusion + 0x625E in clr.dll 1952    
0x5B956127 CreateApplicationContext + 0x11D4 in clr.dll 1952    
0x5B8EC496 GetCLRFunction + 0x21C in clr.dll    1952    
0x5B8EC439 GetCLRFunction + 0x1BF in clr.dll    1952    
0x5B8ED055 GetCLRFunction + 0xDDB in clr.dll    1952    
0x5B96AF00 _CorExeMain + 0x1C in clr.dll    1952
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AQtime 5.45 does not support Win7 - to profile under this OS, you will need to get a newer version.
But Vista is supported in 5.45. However, without additional details, it is hard to guess the reason of the problem. There is a good online resource - [AQtime Troubleshooter](http://www.automatedqa.com/support/about-troubleshooter/), consider using it to perform basic troubleshooting of the problem. I guess excluding some elements from profiling will solve the problem. You can start with disabling the "Profile Entire .NET Code" area.

Alex

Comment: Hi Alex, I follow your advise by going on AQtime troubleshooter, and followed the steps however at some point they ask me to upload some dump file located in the Logs folder, the problem is that on my computer this folder is totally empty (meaning that aqtime does not go that far in the profiling). If you need additional details just ask  me which one you need ;)

Comment: I'm currently trying only with windows vista as win7 is not supported :p also i did not check "Profile Entire .Net Code" only the "Full check by routine" selected with the "by Routine" option. I'm also getting only one line in the report when checking "Profile <Root> routine" (le line is the root routine infos) but no more ..

Comment: Oh and also i get a warning about the SpeedTest technology on my processor that may cause inaccurate timing because of the dynamic CPU frequency ;) does that help you understanding my problem ? ;)

Comment: The fact that Troubleshooter asks you to upload a dump file means that you selected the "AQtime crashes" option. This is not the case, according to your description - this is the application being profiled who crashes because of AQtime profiling it :) What version of .NET Framework do you have on your PC? AQtime 5.45 supports versions up to 3.5.

Comment: maybe that's the problem then because i'm trying to profile a .net 4.0 application :p so again i guess if i want to profile that application i also have to get another license for the version 7 of AQtime. Anyway thanks for your time and your explanations, they helped me a lot in understanding the problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

Hit the same problem today, when upgrading to Windows 7 (64 bit).  The [standard version of AQTime 7](http://smartbear.com/products/free-tools/aqtime-standard/) is now a free product however and may meet your needs.  I'm going to try this to see how I get on, and [upgrade back to the pro version](http://www.automatedqa.com/order/add-to-cart/?tid=31&tab=2) as and when I need to.  Kind of hoping I don't need to, but the upgrade is cheap enough, and I've had good value out of this tool over the years.